# Appending random bytes to an image doesn't change the outcome?

Tags: objective-c, image, random, md5

So to simplify the situation I want to append a couple random bytes to an image to change the MD5 hash every time.

I have the code set up to look up the image then create an NSImage. After that it converts the NSImage to NSMutableData which offers me the opportunity to append random bytes. I then end it all by exporting the altered NSImage to the desktop.

That all works fine and dandy until I run my program twice and compare the MD5 hashes of the two outputs. They are exactly the same! It doesn't matter if I append 1 or 1000 random bytes, if you compare the two outputs, it is exactly the same to each other.

My code:

```
- (void)createNewImage:(NSString *)filePath {
// NSImage from path
NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// NSData to NSMutableData
NSData *imgData = [newImage TIFFRepresentation];
NSMutableData *mutableData = [imgData mutableCopy];

// Get the random bytes
NSData *randomData = [self createRandomBytes:10];

// Append random data to new image
[mutableData appendData:randomData];

(etc...)

// Create file path for the new image
NSString *fileName = @"/Users/Computer/Desktop/MD5/newImage.jpg";

// Cache the new image
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:mutableData];
NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
NSData *newData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps];
[newData writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];

}

-(NSData *)createRandomBytes:(NSUInteger)amount {
return [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/dev/random"] readDataOfLength:amount];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With the help of picciano, I found that exporting the edited NSData directly manages to achieve my goal

```
[mutableData writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

HOWEVER, the image is significantly larger. The source image is 182 KB while the new images are 503 KBs. picciano's answer explains why this happens but does anyone happen to have a workaround to the inflation?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding random data, but it is not being used in creating the image. When the image is converted back to a JPG data representation, only the valid portion of the image data is used.

To verify this, check the length of your `newData` object.

Comment: So is my goal even possible? This information is helpful but renders my program kind of useless.

Comment: @JWP - You could always manipulate bytes inside the image data.  Ideally figure out how to flip a few least-significant bits, so the visual image is minimally affected.

Comment: Good call, Hot Licks. Sort of like image water marking.